# IE Display Issue for width of <td>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

All,
I basically have two identical pages from a coding perspective. The first page is:

http://tinyurl.com/7rv59q3

The second page is:

http://tinyurl.com/7a7zyp8

However, in the second one IE adds extra spacing between the image and the other text. Does anyone have any idea why it would do this? In Chrome, Safari, FF it displays perfectly fine.

I can't inspect elements in IE because it isn't there so I'm not sure what is wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can inspect elements with IE, go to tools > developer tools and use find to click on the element you want to inspect

Comment: May I ask, why is it a table? I see the rest of the page has html5 tags. Why make the content of the page wrapped in a table?

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to the `width=''` attributes on your `<td>`s. These should not be there anyway, you should use CSS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of internet explorer do not correctly ignore whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) when rendering pages.  Your second example has a number of tabs after the image, which causes older versions of IE (or IE9 in compatibility mode) to put extra space after the image.

Comment: Does anyone else remember carrying the closing tag of an image over to the next line so that IE wouldn't put extra space to the right of an image?  Ugh.